# What is the FIRST and FOLLOW sets for this grammar...

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

With the definitions of FIRST being the set of terminal symbols that begin strings derived from α, and FOLLOW being:

```
FOLLOW(A) = { a | S ⇒* αAaβ }
```

What are the FIRST and the FOLLOW sets for the following grammar?

```
E1 → E2F1end 
F1 → +E1 | ε 
E2 → numF2 
F2 → *E2 | ε
```

I'm thinking:

```
FIRST(E1) is {num}
FIRST(F1) is {+, ε}
FIRST(E2) is {num}
FIRST(F2) is {*, ε}
```

Not a clue for the the follow sets though.

Comment: Might help to clearly and explicitly define everything.

Comment: What do you mean @TheCount ?

Comment: I mean that this is very hard to parse without your definitions of everything that you're doing. What are your conventions for "FIRST" and "FOLLOW"?

Comment: I've edited my question, is this clearer now @TheCount ?